# Gradle 2.3 + JUnit 4.11 = broken Charset

Tags: java, unicode, junit, character-encoding, gradle

Under normal conditions in the correct bytes written to the file, but in conjunction Gradle 2.3 + JUnit 4.11 unexpected result.

```
import org.junit.Test;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

public class TestUTF16Test
{
   @Test
   public void testWrite() throws Exception
   {
      try (FileOutputStream bin = new FileOutputStream("testUTF16junit.txt")) {
         bin.write("Русский".getBytes("UTF-16LE"));
      }
   }
}
```

build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'java'

sourceCompatibility = 1.7
version = '1.0'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11'
}
```

$ gradle.bat :clean :test

```
:clean
:compileJavawarning: [options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 1.7
1 warning

:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:classes
:compileTestJavawarning: [options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 1.7
1 warning

:processTestResources UP-TO-DATE
:testClasses
:test

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 4.999 secs
```

Result:

```
20 04 A0 00 21 04 53 04 21 04 03 04 21 04 03 04... 28 bytes
```

But it should be:

```
20 04 43 04 41 04 41 04 3A 04 38 04 39 04 = 14 bytes
```

OS: Microsoft Windows 7 [Version 6.1.7601]

Comment: Running the same test using your IDE gives you the expected result? If - then what encoding did you setup for your source files? And what encoding is your JVM's default encoding?

Answer (score 2):

Gradle fix

```
[ compileJava, compileTestJava ]*.options*.encoding = 'UTF-8'
```

2015, and javac can not recognize Unicode for BOM!

```
>javac.exe src\test\java\TestUTF16Test.java
src\test\java\TestUTF16Test.java:1: error: illegal character: '\u00bb'
я╗┐import org.junit.Test;
 ^
1 error

>javac.exe -version
javac 1.8.0_25
```

Now I understand why IDE doesn't add BOM...